TypeORM relation not loaded causes type mismatch in NestJS unit test
Question

I'm building a small backend API with NestJS, using MySQL and TypeORM. I have an Organisation entity with a relation to a list of KnowledgeDataPool[]. When I call find() on the TypeORM repository, it returns a list of Organisation objects, but without the KnowledgeDataPool[] relation, which is expected.
The issue arises when testing the controller. The organisationRepository.find() method is typed to return Promise<Organisation[]>, but the returned objects don’t include the knowledgeDataPools field. This causes a type mismatch during testing.
Should I change the return type of organisationService.findAll() to DeepPartial or Partial? And why doesn’t organisationRepository.find() return Partial by default?
Or am I missing some thing?
SomeCode

The organisation Class:
@Entity()
export class Organisation {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(
    () => KnowledgeDataPool,
    (knowledgeDataPool) => knowledgeDataPool.organisation,
    {
      cascade: true,
    },
  )
  @JoinTable()
  knowledgeDataPools: KnowledgeDataPool[]; // <--- Notice this relation.
}

I have a Service for my organisations:
@Injectable()
export class OrganisationService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Organisation)
    private organsiationRepository: Repository<Organisation>,
  ) {}

  ...

  findAll(): Promise<Organisation[]> {
    return this.organsiationRepository.find();
  }

  ...
}

And a controller calling this Service:
export class OrganisationController {
  constructor(private readonly organisationService: OrganisationService) {}

  ...

  @Get()
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Get all oranisations.' })
  findAll() {
    return this.organisationService.findAll();
  }

  ...
}

Know when I want to test the controller:
describe('OrganisationController', () => {
  let organisationController: OrganisationController;
  let organisationService: OrganisationService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const mockOrganisationService = {
      findAll: jest.fn(),
      ...
    };

    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [OrganisationController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: OrganisationService,
          useValue: mockOrganisationService, // Use the mock service
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    organisationController = module.get<OrganisationController>(OrganisationController);
    organisationService = module.get<OrganisationService>(OrganisationService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(organisationController).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('findAll', () => {
    it('should return an array of organisations', async () => {
      const result: = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Example', // No knowledgeDataPools in the actual result
        },
      ];

      // Mock the service method
      jest.spyOn(organisationService, 'findAll').mockResolvedValue(result); // <--- Error is shown here

      // Call the controller method
      expect(await organisationController.findAll()).toEqual(result);
    });
  });

  ...
} 

I get this error message:
Argument of type '{ id: number; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Organisation[] | Promise<Organisation[]>'.
  Type '{ id: number; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Organisation[]'.
    Property 'knowledgeDataPools' is missing in type '{ id: number; name: string; }' but required in type 'Organisation'.


https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/relational-query-builder
Like here you need to specify the realtion
 // Find all organisations with their related KnowledgeDataPool entities
  findAll(): Promise<Organisation[]> {
    return this.organisationRepository.find({
      relations: ['knowledgeDataPools'], // Specify the relation here
    });
  }

 findOne(id: number): Promise<Organisation> {
    return this.organisationRepository.findOne({
      where: { id },
      relations: ['knowledgeDataPools'], // Specify the relation here
    });
  }


Yes, this would work! In this case, I don't want to return the relation when calling findAll().  In particular, this relation is only returned when calling findOne(id);

updated the answer

Unfortunately, still not what I was looking for. I'm O.K. with findAll() not returning the Relation. I'm just not sure which type findAll() should return. Because when its Organisation[] I get problems when testing.
